# Control Number of Processes in Python using multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, process, multiprocessing

I would like to control the number of Processes spawned while using the multiprocessing package.

Say I only want three processes active at the same time. The only way I know how to do this is:

```
import multiprocessing
import Queue
def worker(arg):
    ## Do stuff
    return returnvalue

argument = list(1,2,3,4,5,6)
aliveprocesses = 0
jobs = Queue.Queue()
for arg in argument:
    while jobs.qsize() > 2:
        jobs.get().join()
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker,args=(arg,))
    jobs.put(p)
    p.start()
```

Basically I only know how to monitor one process at a time using the Process.join() function. I monitor the oldest process until it is done and then create a new process. For my program the oldest process should finish before the others, on average. But who knows? Maybe another process finishes first and I would have no way of knowing.

The only alternative I can think of is something like this:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
def worker(arg):
    ## Do stuff
    return returnvalue

argument = list(1,2,3,4,5,6)
aliveprocesses = 0
jobs = set()
for arg in argument:
    while aliveprocesses > 2:
        for j in jobs:
            if not j.is_alive():
                aliveprocesses -= 1
                break
            time.sleep(1)
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker,args=(arg,))
    jobs.put(p)
    p.start()
    aliveprocesses += 1
```

In the above function you are checking all of processes if they are still alive. If they are all still alive you sleep for a bit and then check again until there is a dead process after which you spawn a new process. The problem here is that from what I understand the time.sleep() function is not a particularly efficient way to wait for a process to end.

Ideally I would like a function "superjoin()" like Process.join() only it uses a set of Process objects and when one Process within the set returns then superjoin() returns. **And superjoin() does not itself use the time.sleep() function ie it's not being "passed the buck"**

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to have a single (parallel) task, instead of managing processes individually, you should use the higher-level [multiprocessing.Pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers), which makes managing the number of processes easier.

You can't `join` a pool, but you have blocking calls (such as [`Pool.map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map)) that perform this kind of task.

If you need finer-grained control, you may want to adapt [Pool's source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/71eda9bd8875/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py)